# How to map out two arrays into array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays

```
keys:[key0, key1, key2, key3]
```

and

```
body:[['jake', 24, 3, true], ['susan', 21, 0, true]]
```

the result I need is

```
[{key0:jake, key1:24, key2:3, key3:true}, {key0:susan, key1:21, key2:0, key3:true}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Map the keys and values to an arrays of pairs of `[key, value]`, and then convert to an object using `Object.fromEntries()` (see `zipObject` function).

To convert an array of values, use `Array.map()` with `zipObject`:

```js
const zipObject = keys => values => Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => [key, values[i]]))

const keys = ['key0', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3']

const values = [['jake', 24, 3, true], ['susan', 21, 0, true]]

const result = values.map(zipObject(keys))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const body = [['jake', 24, 3, true], ['susan', 21, 0, true]];
const keys = ['key0', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3']
let newArray = [];

numbers.forEach((value) =>
{
    let obj={};
    keys.forEach((key,index) => 
{
        obj[`${key}`] = value[index];
        
    })
    newArray.push(obj);
    
});
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be one simple way to do this, using easy to read loops:

```
const keys = ['key0', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
const body = [['jake', 24, 3, true], ['susan', 21, 0, true]];
const result = [];
for (let b of body) {
    const obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        obj[keys[i]] = b[i];
    }
    result.push(obj);
}
console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
[
  { key0: 'jake', key1: 24, key2: 3, key3: true },
  { key0: 'susan', key1: 21, key2: 0, key3: true }
]
```